# MassTransit get response from consumer

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, rabbitmq, masstransit, consumer

Hi does enybody knows how to solve following problem in MassTransit: Consumer gets request and response on it but response does not back into client.Request.  method. I have created project in ASP NET WEB API and i have implemented Request/Response communication by IRequestClient interface:

```
public class RequestResponseCommandProvider<TRequest, TResponse>
    : IRequestResponseCommandProvider<TRequest, TResponse>
    where TRequest : class, ICommandQueueName
    where TResponse : class
{
    private readonly IBusControl _bus;
    private readonly string _hostUri;
    public RequestResponseCommandProvider(IBusControl bus,
        string hostUri)
    {
        _bus = bus;
        _hostUri = hostUri;
    }

    public TResponse RequestResponseCommand(TRequest command)
    {
        _bus.Start();
        var serviceAddress = new Uri(_hostUri + command.QueueName);
        IRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse> client =
            _bus.CreateRequestClient<TRequest, TResponse>(serviceAddress, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        return client.Request(command).Result; //there should back response
    }
}
```

I have created configuration of serviceBus as Module in Autofac:

```
public class BusModule : Autofac.Module
{
    private readonly string _hostUri;
    IEnumerable<IConfigurableConsumer> _consumers;

    public BusModule(string hostUri, IEnumerable<IConfigurableConsumer> consumers)
    {
        _hostUri = hostUri;
        _consumers = consumers;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

        builder.Register(r => Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(sfc =>
        {
            var host = sfc.Host(new Uri(_hostUri), h =>
            {
                h.Username("guest");
                h.Password("guest");
            });

            if (_consumers != null)
            {
                foreach (var consumer in _consumers)
                {
                    consumer.Configure(sfc);
                }
            }
        }))
        .As<IBus>()
        .As<IBusControl>()
        .SingleInstance();

        builder.RegisterType<RecieveObserver>()
            .As<IReceiveObserver>();
    }
}
```

Consumers are added by constructor.
Provider is injected into service:

```
public class TestLayer : ITestLayer
{
    private readonly IRequestResponseCommandProvider<IAddTestCommand, ResponseCommand> _provider;
    public TestLayer(
        IRequestResponseCommandProvider<IAddTestCommand, ResponseCommand> provider)
    {
        _provider = provider;
    }
    public ServiceResult CreateTest(TestRecord record)
    {
        ServiceResult result;
        try
        {
            var tmp = _provider.RequestResponseCommand(new AddTestCommand() { Record = "d3d32" });
            result = new ServiceResult();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            result = new ServiceResult();
            result.AddError($"Wystąpił problem podczas zapisu do bazy danych: {ex}");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

When I check queues in RabbitMQ all messages looks like this one:
[RabbitMQ queue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJX8h.png)

I have already seen Sample-RequestResponse made by Chris Patterson but i have problem when I use dependency injectiion.
I will be grateful for help what i have done wrong.. There is also all repository on GitHub where you can find simple project where this code is included and still doesnt work: [My GitHub](https://github.com/Pawelh133/BrainShelf)

Answer (score 2):

Two issues:

1. Lazy instantiation of the bus is not a good idea, since it takes quite some time and in your case you will get a long timeout when `IBus` will be resolved first time.
2. You are not getting any reply because you need to start the bus for it to receive anything at all. If you do not start the bus, you can only send.

Comment: Indeed, we need start the bus to can receive response